# Opencv_world451.dll missing in openCV 4.5.1 x86 build

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm upgrading my Visual Studio v15 C++ project from openCV v3.4.3 to v4.5.1 in x86 configuration. I built it in CMake and then ran BUILD and INSTALL in OpenCV.sln in Visual Studio. But I cannot find the opencv_world451.dll anywhere. It's supposed to be in ..\install\x86\vc15\bin but it's just not there. There are bunch of other dll files, but not the opencv_world451.dll. Could anyone help?

Comment: related https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-world451-dll-missing-in-x86-build/687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cmake variable `BUILD_opencv_world` needs to be set according to your wishes.

use cmake-gui for convenience.